# Programatically add images in simple product (using Object Manager Magento 2.3.7)

Tags: magento2

I'm using the Object Manager in order to add a few products from a csv (based on https://magecomp.com/blog/import-product-data-programmatically-magento-2/ ). So far everything is working and my images are temporarily stored in "var/tempImages/". When I pass that path into:

```
//$img is my path to "product.jpg", etc.

                    ->setImage($img)
                    ->setSmallImage($img)
                    ->setThumbnail($img)
```

Images are not loading at all (doubled checked, they're in said path).

Any pointers on what could be missing to correctly map the path to image (or if I'm in something completely different).

Thanks.

Comment: Are you passing a full path? You can find example in test: vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Catalog/_files/product_with_image.php

Comment: I was using a relative path, but not for pub/media. Thanks for the link, helped a lot to figure the error.